# Default queueing of Lumen Mailables

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, lumen

From Laravel documentation:

> Queueing By Default
>
> If you have mailable classes that you want to always be queued, you
>   may implement the  ShouldQueue contract on the class. Now, even if you
>   call the send method when mailing, the mailable will still be queued
>   since it implements the contract

Is there a way to default queue emails even when calling Mail:send as in Laravel but in Lumen?

I've tried implementing the ShouldQueue contract on my Mailables but they still get sent right away, my queues are working as I use them explictly in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have `QUEUE_DRIVER` other than `sync` in `.env` file. Use `database`, `beanstalkd`, or `redis` driver.

Second, if you get `queue is null` error, you must bind the queue first.

```
app('queue');
Mail::to($email)->send($mailable);
```

or if your mailable doesn't implement ShouldQueue

```
app('queue');
Mail::to($email)->queue($mailable);
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/77)